# Create a Application in Azure AD with Azure PowerShell Certificate authentication

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I was trying to Create a Application in Azure AD with Azure PowerShell Certificate authentication, below is the Powershell snippet:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
$cert = New-Object    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate("PATH_TO_CER_FILE")
$key = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())
$app = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "SetupTet4" -HomePage  "http://localhost" -IdentifierUris "http://localhost" -KeyValue $key -KeyType AsymmetricX509Cert
New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName "Owner" -ServicePrincipalName  $app.ApplicationId
```

the Azure AD application was created successfully, however for Azure AD application with Certificate Authentication, the `customKeyIdentifier` and value of in the `keyCredentials` is null after creation, this is the portion of manifest of my application I downloaded from Azure portal:

```
"keyCredentials": [{
"customKeyIdentifier": null,
"endDate": "2017-02-25T20:48:35.5174541Z",
"keyId": "575580cc-ce4e-4862-ad3e-1ba5833fe7f6",
"startDate": "2016-02-25T20:48:35.5174541Z",
"type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
"usage": "Verify",
"value": null
}],
```

FYI the certificate is a self signed certificate I use makecert command generated locally.

Any advice, great appreciate.

James

Comment: What's the question?  The steps you posted are the steps to create the application in Azure AD.  What is the concern you have with customKeyIdentifier and value being null?

Comment: Rick, thanks for asking, that's the issue, if the  customKeyIdentifier and value is null, the App Authentication will fail.

Comment: I also try the Graph API, follow this code: [link] (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/tree/master/GraphConsoleAppV3)  however the result is same,  customKeyIdentifier and value is null,   it’s a bug in MS API or I missed something?

Comment: I just noticed what you're missing - "Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy".  I have this same environment deployed.  I just checked my script and realized this was missing in yours.  I'll post this as a solution in a few mins so you can see the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a call to **Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy** to specify the access level you want the service principle to have for the key vault.  See the changes in the last two lines for your script.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
$cert = New-Object    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate("PATH_TO_CER_FILE")
$key = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())
$app = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "SetupTet4" -HomePage  "http://localhost" -IdentifierUris "http://localhost" -KeyValue $key -KeyType AsymmetricX509Cert
$sp = New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName "<your-vault-name>" `
    -ServicePrincipalName $sp.ServicePrincipalName `
    -PermissionsToKeys all -PermissionsToSecrets all `
    -ResourceGroupName "<your-resource-group-name>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply,  even with Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy, it's "value" property is still null (whereas I did previously put my public cert in it) ... Does it mean it is really null or just an empty property for security reasons ??

Comment: Did you try running your application?  I'm able to authenticate using the certificate and access the vault successfully from the app.  And this value is null in my environment too.  What leads you to believe that this is what your problem is?

Comment: Rick, you're right the null in the value seems doesn't matter, thx for taking a look.

Comment: Rick, another question is if I use Graph API to create the application in Azure AD, I can set the the required access use this function:  appObject.RequiredResourceAccess.Add(officeAccess);  is it possible to do the same thing using Powershell?   certainly I can use Graph API to create the application and do the whole thing, but to use the Graph API, I have to manually create another Application first, which is not very convenient.

Comment: I'm not aware of a specific PowerShell function to do this.  Still, PowerShell essentially wraps the API's and just presents them to you in a simplified interface.  If you don't find a command to do what you want you can always using PowerShell to invoke the Graph API directly.

Comment: $app = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "SetupTet4" -HomePage  "http://localhost" -IdentifierUris "http://localhost" -KeyValue $key -KeyType AsymmetricX509Cert
$sp = New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName "<your-vault-name>" `
    -ServicePrincipalName $sp.ServicePrincipalName `
    -PermissionsToKeys all -PermissionsToSecrets all `
    -ResourceGroupName "<your-resource-group-name>"